# Java FileNotFoundException in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: java, ubuntu, jboss

I have ubuntu 12.04 where i have installed JDK 7 , Jboss Server AS 7.1.1 and running my application successfully.The problem is in my java application i am editing a xml file at runtime to update the content of file. It is working fine in window but in ubuntu it is throwing FileNotFoundException.

But i checked manually file is there.

Can you please help me . Is it like you can't change files at run time in ubuntu or some admin privileges.

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /home/azureuser/ranveer/hopscotch/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/Hop.ear/entre.war/config/datacon/DaoConfig.xml
>   (No such file or directory) 04:04:33,219 ERROR [stderr]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>   04:04:33,219 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146) 04:04:33,220 ERROR
>   [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:101) 04:04:33,220 ERROR
>   [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
>   04:04:33,220 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
>   04:04:33,220 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) at
>   java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037) 04:04:33,221 ERROR [stderr]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) ... 118 more

Comment: You try and edit a config file _within a jar_ at _runtime_? I am surprised that it works at all even under Windows

Comment: does the file exist at mentioned path or is it really trying to read a file from ear and war file ?

Comment: @fge no i am not editing jar file. Its just simple xml file in a folder which i am accessing using context path to edit that xml file

Comment: @JigarJoshi this file is in war file. The war is containing a folder in which that xml file is existing. It works great in window but dont know why FileNotFoundException in ubuntu . I went to that path in ubuntu the file is already there still not been able to find that file. dont know why this is happening

Comment: It cannot just read a file from war file as `File`, please check the path in windows from where it is reading, I doubt it is reading from extracted path not from war file

Comment: You probably want to use `Class.getResourceAsStream()` or something instead

Comment: @JigarJoshi i have checked now. In windows it is taking from war file only this is the path.

D:\Zeno\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\Hop.ear\entre.war\config\datacon\DaoConfig.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd triple-check the existence of the file, taking into account case sensitivity (especially since you mentioned it works on windows).
Also according to documentation the exception name is misleading: it could indicate other problems e.g. permissions or having a directory instead of a file.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream(java.io.File)

Comment: Yes, `FileNotFoundException` sucks, however the exception message here _does_ say `No such file or directory`.

Comment: @Pelit Mamani Thanks Man. case sensitivity was the problem.
it was DaoConfig.xml but the file name is DAOConfig.xml. 

Thanks :)